# Excel VBA comparing column with input value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm noob on excel macros and I'm trying to make a macro like :

I want to input some number and compare it with value in A column

ex:

**A column** in excel have :

**1234**

**1233**

**1236**

and my input is:

**1234**

result :

**B column**

**1**        > 1234 - 1234 (find once)

**0**        > 1234 - 1233 (not same)

**0**        > 1234 - 1236 (not same)

**C column**

**1233**     > first value that not the same with input

**1236**     > second value that not the same with input

Right now i just know how to input the value :( something like this :

```
Sub getInput()

    MyInput = InputBox("Enter Number")
    MsgBox ("Searching") & MyInput

End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you just let the user enter it in a cell and then use formula's to get what you want?

Comment: I'm trying to make a macro for this, and I can enter the input into a cell, but dunno what to do now :(

Comment: Will Col A have duplicates?

Comment: `1 > 1234 - 1234 (find once)` so if 1234 is repeated 5 times in Col A then in every instance you want 5 in Col B? or you want to show `1` everywhere there is a dup?

Comment: @SiddharthRout 5 in col B

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, so I will share

```
Sub getInput()

    Dim i As Integer           ' Integer used in 'For' loop
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim total As Integer
    Dim save As Integer

Do
MyInput = InputBox("Enter Number")

If MyInput = "" Then

    Exit Sub

Else

    MsgBox ("Searching ") & MyInput

    total = 0
    x = 2
    y = x + 1

    For i = 1 To 3         'hardcode - 3 because I have 3 value in A
        Cells(i, y).Value = ""
        If Int(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Int(MyInput) Then
            ' A match has been found to the supplied string
            ' Store the current row number and exit the 'For' Loop
            total = total + 1
            If Cells(i, x).Value = 0 Then

            Cells(i, x).Value = Int(total)
            Else
            Cells(i, x).Value = Int(Cells(i, x).Value) + Int(total)
            End If

        Else
            Cells(i, y).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

    ' Pop up a message box to let the user know if the text

    If total = 0 Then
        MsgBox "String " & MyInput & " not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "String " & MyInput & " found"
    End If
    x = x + 1
End If

Loop Until MyInput = ""    'Loop until user press cancel or input blank data

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried by entering a value through inputbox to sheet first.
Hope it Helps

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim myformula As String
    Dim lr As Long
    With Sheets(1)
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Range("p1").Value = Application.InputBox("Enter Number", , , , , , 1)

    Range("B1").Select
    myformula = "=IF(R1C16=RC[-1],1,0)"
    Range("b1").Formula = myformula
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault


    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(C[-1]=0,C[-2],"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C1:C" & lr), Type:=xlFillDefault

   End With

End Sub
```